# Checking translations of predicate logic

Tags: logic, translation, predicate-logic

Let Dx = "x is a detective", U12 = "1 is the uncle of 2", and appropriate lowercase letters for names.

1. If there are any detectives, John is the only detective.
2. No detective is John's uncle.

My attempts:

1. ∃x(Dx ∧ (Dj ∧ ∀y (Dy → y=j)) ∧ x=y). I know this isn't correct, because it doesn't take the if/then form. But my thought process is the following, which seems to capture what the sentence is saying? There is at least one x such that: (i) x is a detective, (ii) John is a detective, and for all y, if y is a detective, y is John, and (iii) x is y (and thus is John). Am I at least on the right track here?
2. ¬∃x (Dx ∧ Uxj). I'm thinking: There is no x such that x is a detective and x is the uncle of John.

Comment: #2 looks right. For #1, why isn't "∀y (Dy → y=j)" sufficient as a translation? I don't see why you need all the other stuff nested around it, and this version allows for the possibility that there are no detectives, *or* that there is one detective and that detective is John (and it seems to me that it forbids more than one detective, because j refers to a unique singular object in this domain of discourse, so there can't be multiple distinct objects, say a pair of them labeled a and b, with the property that a=j and b=j)

Comment: @Hypnosifl  "For all persons: if that person is a detective, then that person is John" is exactly that "If a person is a detective, then John is the only detective."

Comment: Thanks for replying, Hypnosifl, and for further clarifying, Graham. For #1, I got thrown off by the "any" and the if/then form, and thought the translation would need to have two parts while trying to keep the ∧ for the ∃x.

Answer (score 2):

> ∃x(Dx ∧ (Dj ∧ ∀y (Dy → y=j)) ∧ x=y). I know this isn't correct,

Indeed, it is not.  You  want the existence to be the antecedent of the conditional, with the consequent being the declaration that John is a detective and that if anybody is a detective then they are John.  There is no need to attempt to link the existential' and the universal's variable.

(∃x Dx) → (Dj ∧ ∀y (Dy → y=j))

This will satisfied should there be no detectives, or else should John be the one and only detective.

This is now correct, but inelegant.

*As Hypnosifl commented*, this is equivalent to saying "For anybody: if they are a detective, then they are John."

**∀y (Dy → y=j)**

This is satisfied should there be no detectives, or should every detective be the one and only John.  As required.

---

> ¬∃x (Dx ∧ Uxj). I'm thinking: There is no x such that x is a detective and x is the uncle of John.

Correct.  Nobody is a detective and John's uncle.